# Firewalld - Allow only few ip adresses - use two zones?

Tags: centos, firewalld

I want to drop incoming communication unless it's from few IP adresses. Is it corect to put interface in one zone (drop) and drop everything (dont configure any services or ports...) and put those few allowed ip addresses to another zone (public) and alow only allowed ports for them? There will be no interface in zone public, only those ip adresses in source.
Here is example:

```
[root@localhost]# firewall-cmd --list-all
drop (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0
  sources:
  services:
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

[root@localhost]# firewall-cmd --list-all --zone=public
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources: 192.168.1.1
  services:
  ports: 443/tcp 443/udp
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text. Copy text as text and use formatting tools to highlight e.g. code.

Comment: Thanks for comment. OK, I'll edit that in a minute :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would leave the interface in zone **public** as is by default and the add the trusted addresses and ports to zone **trusted**. I believe this way the firewall configuration will be more intuitive.

Comment: But in general, this two zone concept is it a good solution? (I have zone drop set as default so I gues its not a big problem..)

Comment: In zone based firewalls this is the correct way to configure access to the services.